# I am wanting to use UDTT in my database, but we have CLR turned off, and according to the docs for create type, all types require a CLR assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr, user-defined-type, user-defined-table-type

Is this true? Or can I use User defined Table Types with having CLR off? (I.e. they don't require the use of CLR)

If they do require CLR, is there an alternative I can use for my stored procedure parameter that serves the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User-Defined Table Types are a TSQL feature, not requiring CLR to be enabled.  Nor are they CLR types "under the covers".  eg

```
exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0
reconfigure with override

go

create type tableType as table(id int)

go
declare @t tableType
insert into @t(id) values (1)

select * from @t
```

Then to show it's not a CLR type "under the covers"  run

```
select * from sys.dm_clr_appdomains
go
declare @t hierarchyid =  hierarchyid::Parse('/1/1/3/')
go
select * from sys.dm_clr_appdomains
```

to see how there's an AppDomain created when you create a `hierarchyid` but not a User-Defined Table Type.

Comment: Adding that system CLR types (hierarchyid,geometry,geography)  work even when `clr enabled` is set to zero. But your answer is correct, of course.

Comment: Just curious so I can show my DBA: do you have any documentation for UDTT not requiring CLR?

Comment: @JackHerer surely proving it trumps documentation? As discussed in the comments to [your cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065535/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-in-a-list-of-table-rows-to-a-stored-procedure?noredirect=1#comment118546230_67065535) though it looks like `CREATE TYPE` documentation is a bit confusing as the preamble is much the same as it was in 2005 before table types were a thing. So it gives the false impression that types are either aliases or CLR. Someone is submitting an edit so hopefully you can show the updated page to the DBA

Comment: Agreed, thank you